# How to POST value of an input field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, null, fetch-api

First I try to set the input value as a variable:

```
window.onload = function() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  return inputValue;
};
```

Then I want to POST the value of the input field through an API call:

```
function getPost(inputValue) {
  return fetch("https://rel.ink/api/links/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      url: inputValue
    })
  }).then(res => res.json());
}

function tinyURL() {
  getPost()
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Success:", data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
}

function addEventListener() {
  document.getElementById("postBtn").addEventListener("click", tinyURL);
}
```

However, the value isn't going through as the `console.log` output is:

> url: Array(1)
> 0: "This field is required."
> length: 1

The API call is successful, but something is going wrong with the input value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not passing the `inputDocument ` to the `getPost` function and `inputValue` is only declared in the `onload` function scope. So you got it all set up, but there is no passing of data from one function to another.

Comment: body: JSON.stringify({
      url: document.getElementById("myInput").value
    })
or if you want to store in any variable store it in getPost function. why you are storing it in window.onload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are taking the value on `window.onload`, always you are passing the same ***initial value of the element*** which probably you do not want.

You should declare the variable in the global scope and update the variable on *input* event:

**Change:**

```
window.onload = function() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  return inputValue;
};
```

**To:**

```
let inputValue;
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener('input', function()
  inputValue = this.value;
});
```

**OR:** You can directly set the current value

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  url: document.getElementById("myInput").value
})
```